# Magento 2 fieldset.xml; copy fields from quote to order

Tags: magento2, fieldsets

I have created a custom model to create order from quote;
I am using fieldset.xml to copy quote custom codes to order. I have created custom columns in both quote and order with matching fields. When order is placed values are storing in quote custom fields but not copying to order. Below  is my fieldset.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
<scope id="global">
    <!--quote convert to order-->
    <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote">            
        <field name="preorder_number">
            <aspect name="to_order" />
        </field>
        <field name="purchase_order_number">
            <aspect name="to_order" />
        </field>
        <field name="reference_number">
            <aspect name="to_order" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <!--quote item convert to order item-->
    <fieldset id="quote_convert_item">
        <field name="preorder_number">
            <aspect name="to_order_item" />
        </field>
        <field name="purchase_order_number">
            <aspect name="to_order_item" />
        </field>
        <field name="reference_number">
            <aspect name="to_order_item" />
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</scope>
```

What else I need to do?

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes i cleared cache and generation both, then also custom fields data are not copying from quote to order

Comment: Any solution for this

Comment: Please add <?xml version="1.0" ?> in that code.i thing that is missing

Answer (score 10):

If you take a look at the current magento2.1 code base you will notice that in [moduleName/etc](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/develop/app/code/Magento/GiftMessage/etc) folder there is a [fieldset.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/GiftMessage/etc/fieldset.xml) with command to copy information from one table to another. However this DO NOT work. If you take a closer look you will also notice [that there is observer](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/GiftMessage/Observer/SalesEventQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver.php) that does the same exact thing. Take a look at  https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5823

To copy from quote* to order* table you will need to use an observer and/or plugin.

In your custom Module events.xml add

```
 <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
    <observer name="[moduelname]_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before" instance="Company\ModuleName\Observer\SaveOrderBeforeSalesModelQuoteObserver" />
</event>
```

Then

```
<?php

namespace Company\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveOrderBeforeSalesModelQuoteObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * List of attributes that should be added to an order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $attributes = [
        'field_1_name_here',
        'field_2_name_here',
        'field_...._here'
    ];


    /**

     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
        /* @var Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote');

        foreach ($this->attributes as $attribute) {
            if ($quote->hasData($attribute)) {
                $order->setData($attribute, $quote->getData($attribute));
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

To copy item from quote_item to order_item, magento seem to have removed the best observer to get the job which was `sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item`. Take a look at this example that should help you copy field from quote_item to order_item table. [How to "add to cart" a product with custom input field and save it to Database?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132009/how-to-add-to-cart-a-product-with-custom-input-field-and-save-it-to-database)

Comment: If you've gotten this far, you might as well use the copy service...

Comment: @LM_Fielding you can see it in my answer how you could use this with the copy service

Comment: this doesnt work of order address. The order created will create a new row for a new order address object. for exmaple my custom data is inserted to order address with ID 500, the new order will use address 501.

Answer (score 8):

Renon Stewart´s answer helped me alot but i could improve it with the official magento developer documentation (http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ext-best-practices/tutorials/copy-fieldsets.html)

In your custom Module events.xml add:

```
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
    <observer name="[moduelname]_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before" instance="Company\ModuleName\Observer\SaveOrderBeforeSalesModelQuoteObserver" />
</event>
```

And in the saveOrderBeforeSalesModelQuoteObserver.php:

```
namespace Company\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveOrderBeforeSalesModelQuoteObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy
     */
    protected $objectCopyService;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy $objectCopyService
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\DataObject\Copy $objectCopyService
    )
    {
        $this->objectCopyService = $objectCopyService;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
        /* @var Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote');

        $this->objectCopyService->copyFieldsetToTarget('sales_convert_quote', 'to_order', $quote, $order);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: HI, i also  used same observer but data is not copy from quote to  order table