# How to "add to cart" a product with custom input field and save it to Database?

Tags: magento2, module, database, magento-2.0, addtocart

I had created a custom module in which I am overriding the **add to cart** form on the product page, and I successfully did it with `catalog_product_view.xml` file. Now I can see a custom input field on the front view of the product page, but I need to post the value of this field to database with Qty, price, etc. and retrieve it again in order history.

I searched a while and also got success in creating new custom columns in `quote_item` & `sales_order` tables. (As per my information, add to cart entries go to `quote_item` and orders after checkout goes to `sales_order` table. If I am wrong about it, please correct me in this as well since I am still a learner.)

I tried a lot and searched for it but didn't find a relevant solution. My vendor name is **Cloudways** and module name is **Mymodule**. Below are the files for my module:

**Cloudways/Mymodule/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Cloudways_Mymodule',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Cloudways/Mymodule/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Cloudways_Mymodule" setup_version="1.0.1"></module>
</config>
```

**Cloudways/Mymodule/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php**

```
<?php

namespace Cloudways\Mymodule\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {

        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        //cart table
        $connection->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('quote_item'),
                'remarks',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Remarks'
                ]
            );
        //Order address table
        $connection->addColumn(
                $installer->getTable('sales_order'),
                'remarks',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'length' => 255,
                    'comment' =>'Remarks'

                ]
            );
        $installer->endSetup(); }
    }
}
```

**Cloudways/Mymodule/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Cloudways_Mymodule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Cloudways_Mymodule::catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Cloudways/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()): ?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       maxlength="12"
                       value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Custom Input Field -->
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="remarks"
                id="remarks"
                maxlength="255"
                placeholder="Remarks"
            />
        </div>
        <!-- Custom Input Field -->
        <br>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $buttonTitle ?></span>
            </button>
            <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation": {
                "radioCheckboxClosest": ".nested"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php else : ?>
<script>
    require([
        'jquery',
        'mage/mage',
        'Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';

        $('#product_addtocart_form').mage('validation', {
            radioCheckboxClosest: '.nested',
            submitHandler: function (form) {
                var widget = $(form).catalogAddToCart({
                    bindSubmit: false
                });

                widget.catalogAddToCart('submitForm', $(form));

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here is the screenshot of front view:

[image]

All I need is to post the value of the custom input field and save it in the database along with the order. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: I MADE RESPECTIVE CHANGES ACCORDING TO THE ANSWER OF R.S. AND HERE IS THE PROBLEM I AM FACING: (P.S. I AM USING MAGENTO 2.0.9)**

[image]

I checked the log file and here is what I have found:

```
[2016-08-26 07:29:38] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Report ID: webapi-57bfefe2d8272; Message: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/41209-54048.cloudwaysapps.com/yyzmyegjdk/public_html/app/code/Cloudways/Mymodule/Observer/SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver.php on line 67' in /home/41209-54048.cloudwaysapps.com/yyzmyegjdk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:194
Stack trace:
#0 /home/41209-54048.cloudwaysapps.com/yyzmyegjdk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
#1 /home/41209-54048.cloudwaysapps.com/yyzmyegjdk/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(163): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
#2 /home/41209-54048.cloudwaysapps.com/yyzmyegjdk/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /home/41209-54048.cloudwaysapps.com/yyzmyegjdk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /home/41209-54048.cloudwaysapps.com/yyzmyegjdk/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 /home/41209-54048.cloudwaysapps.com/yyzmyegjdk/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 {main} [] []
```

**Any suggestions please?**

Comment: Take a look at this magento 1 example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412074/magento-quote-order-product-item-attribute-based-on-user-input/9496266#9496266 ... you should be able to use "additional_options" to store this info using an observer https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=additional_options ... Using additional_options will automatically show this info in admin,  sales order email etc

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a simple product with custom options to accomplish this?

Comment: @R.S I need to do it programmatically because we will further extend this custom cart with different custom options which I think can only be done with custom module.

Comment: Can you add a (github) link to your code, so I can download and try to implement additional_options

Comment: @R.S Yes sure, please give me few mins.

Comment: @R.S here you go:

https://github.com/fayyazgt/Cloudways_Mymodule

Comment: @R.S any suggestions you have for me?

Comment: @R.S please check the problem I am facing. I had edited the question.

Comment: My code was tested against 2.1, is there a reason you are not using 2.1? By default magento will not copy field from quote* table to order*  table see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124712/magento-2-fieldset-xml-copy-fields-from-quote-to-order/

Comment: @R.S foreach($this->quote->getItems() as $item) this foreach loop in SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver.php

Comment: Delete the event for `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` and  SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver.php then try using "Method #2" Plugin.

Comment: @R.S Alright, let me try this.

Comment: I trying to use that extension in magento version 2.2.4 but after add to cart showing this error '1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.' please help me for that issue , Thanks

Comment: @SandeepV If you are getting [invalidargumentexception] "unable to unserialize value," use json_encode and json_decode instead of serialize and unserialize function in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To accomplish this you could use Magento built-in "additional_options" functionality so that you don't have to edit email template, admin order view, customer order view (etc) to display your custom options.

Github : https://github.com/srenon/Cloudways_Mymodule

/app/code/MagePal/CustomItemAddToCart/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="magepal_Customitemaddtocart_checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="MagePal\CustomItemAddToCart\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="magepal_Customitemaddtocart_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before" instance="MagePal\CustomItemAddToCart\Observer\SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Add Option to Quote**

/app/code/MagePal/CustomItemAddToCart/Observer/CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace MagePal\CustomItemAddToCart\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_request;

    /**
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request){
            $this->_request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        /* @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

        $additionalOptions = array();

        if ($additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')){
            $additionalOptions = (array) unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
        }

        $post = $this->_request->getParam('magepal');

        if(is_array($post)){
            foreach($post as $key => $value){
                if($key == '' || $value == ''){
                    continue;
                }

                $additionalOptions[] = [
                    'label' => $key,
                    'value' => $value
                ];
            }
        }

        if(count($additionalOptions) > 0){
            $item->addOption(array(
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
            ));
        }


        /* To Do */

        // Edit Cart - May need to remove option and read them
        // Pre-fill remarks on product edit pages


        /* Issues */

        // Create new cart item with identical option values will add a new line item, instead of increment the previous item qty

    }
}
```

**Method #1 - Copying Option from quote_item to order_item using Observer** See [Magento 2 fieldset.xml; copy fields from quote to order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124712/magento-2-fieldset-xml-copy-fields-from-quote-to-order/)

/app/code/MagePal/CustomItemAddToCart/Observer/SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver.php

```
<?php

namespace MagePal\CustomItemAddToCart\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    private $quoteItems = [];

    private $quote = null;
    private $order = null;

    /**
     * Add order information into GA block to render on checkout success pages
     *
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {

        $this->quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $this->order = $observer->getOrder();

        // can not find an equivalent event for sales_convert_quote_item_to_order_item


        /* @var  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem */
        foreach($this->order->getItems() as $orderItem){
            if(!$orderItem->getParentItemId() && $orderItem->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE){

                if($quoteItem = $this->getQuoteItemById($orderItem->getQuoteItemId())){
                    if ($additionalOptionsQuote = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {

                        //Todo
                        // - check to make sure element are not added twice
                        // - $additionalOptionsQuote - may not be an array
                        if($additionalOptionsOrder = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options')){
                            $additionalOptions = array_merge($additionalOptionsQuote, $additionalOptionsOrder);
                        }
                        else{
                            $additionalOptions = $additionalOptionsQuote;
                        }


                        if(count($additionalOptions) > 0){
                            $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                            //As of Magento ~2.2, the unserialize() was discontinued in favor of json_encode.
                            // See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/serialized-to-json-data-upgrade.html 
                            $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                            $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }


    private function getQuoteItemById($id){
        if(empty($this->quoteItems)){
            /* @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
            foreach($this->quote->getItems() as $item){

                //filter out config/bundle etc product
                if(!$item->getParentItemId() && $item->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE){
                    $this->quoteItems[$item->getId()] = $item;
                }
            }
        }


        if(array_key_exists($id, $this->quoteItems)){
            return $this->quoteItems[$id];
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Method #2 - Copying Option from quote_item to order_item using Plugin**

/app/code/MagePal/CustomItemAddToCart/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem">
        <plugin name="magepal_Customitemaddtocart_Sales_Quote_Item_ToOrderItem" type="MagePal\CustomItemAddToCart\Plugin\QuoteItemToOrderItemPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

/app/code/MagePal/CustomItemAddToCart/Plugin/QuoteItemToOrderItemPlugin.php

```
<?php

namespace MagePal\CustomItemAddToCart\Plugin;

class QuoteItemToOrderItemPlugin
{

    public function aroundConvert(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject, callable $proceed, $quoteItem, $data)
    {

        // get order item
        $orderItem = $proceed($quoteItem, $data);
        
        
        if(!$orderItem->getParentItemId() && $orderItem->getProductType() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE){
            if ($additionalOptionsQuote = $quoteItem->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
                //To do
                // - check to make sure element are not added twice
                // - $additionalOptionsQuote - may not be an array
                if($additionalOptionsOrder = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('additional_options')){
                    $additionalOptions = array_merge($additionalOptionsQuote, $additionalOptionsOrder);
                }
                else{
                    $additionalOptions = $additionalOptionsQuote;
                }

                //As of Magento ~2.2, the unserialize() was discontinued in favor of json_encode.
                // See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/serialized-to-json-data-upgrade.html 
                if(count($additionalOptions) > 0){
                    $options = $orderItem->getProductOptions();
                    $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($additionalOptions->getValue());
                    $orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

[image: Shopping cart and Admin order view page]

Base off of [Magento1 - Quote/order product item attribute based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412074/magento-quote-order-product-item-attribute-based-on-user-input/9496266#9496266)

Comment: @renon I tried above functionality for simple product and it worked out great, thanks! but I need the same for **configurable** product but I get following error on cart page "Selected option(s) or their combination is not currently available." I know why this issue arises, but is there any way to overcome it, I mean filter out particular options?

Comment: Just used this and it works like a charm. Thanks! Are you aware of any functionality in Magento that really allows properties per item (not per product)? For example a custom text on a shirt, but while having multiple of the same shirts with different texts. Magento now combines those products in the cart and thus I lose those really specific settings per item.

Comment: @Nausif, I was facing same issue, but now it resolved. Refer this url - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177133/magento-2-some-item-options-or-their-combination-are-not-currently-available

Comment: @renon I use this and values are showing in mini-cart, cart and checkout. I have configurable product to do this. I tried both the Quote conversion methods, but values not showing in order mail and order section in admin.

Comment: If anyone getting `[invalidargumentexception] unable to unserialize value.` use json_encode and json_decode instead of serialize and unserialize

Comment: Anyone know how to change the option on update page.

Comment: @Renon Stewart I have used json_encode and json_decode instead of serialize and unserialize but issue is not resolve can you please help me..!

Comment: @SanjayGohil... What exact issue are you having?

Comment: @Renon Stewart Issue is solved now..! Thanks

Comment: @RenonStewart is it possible to set custom option from controller?

Comment: how did you solved this  [invalidargumentexception] unable to unserialize value.

Comment: On shopping cart page it showing error now - [invalidargumentexception] unable to unserialize value

Comment: As of Magento ~2.2, the unserialize() was discontinued in favor of json_encode See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/serialized-to-json-data-upgrade.html

Answer (score 1):

If you get in Product View this error: {"message":"Unable to unserialize value. Error: Syntax error"}

or

if you get the jQuery error: Uncaught Error: [object Object]

Change in the inside of SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver.php and CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver.php :

*serialize* to **json_encode**

and

*unserialize* to **json_decode**

Now the next problem. If you tried before to go to the checkout with serialze and you were logged in with an user account, you need to delete the last quote item.

You need to delete in the database inside the quote table the last quote with the used e-mail.

If you can't complete the checkout process, change the SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBeforeObserver.php file on line 50:

```
if(count($additionalOptions) > 0)
```

to:

```
if(is_array($additionalOptions) && count($additionalOptions) > 0){
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this problem:
// Create new cart item with identical option values will add a new line item, instead of increment previous item qty

I have added  after plugin for method representProduct in Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item. In plugin i check is it my needed additional param and if it is return needed result (true).

Answer (score 0):

This github solution https://github.com/srenon/Cloudways_Mymodule is not working for version 2.3. The error is to use PHP unserialize and serialize function. Can any one update this code for 2.3 version?

Comment: This solution will fix your problem.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328949/magento-2-passing-values-from-product-page-to-cart

Answer (score 0):

for version 2.3 and above The error is to use PHP unserialize and serialize function.Every one Can update this code for 2.3 and above using below solution.
[Magento 2 - Passing Values From Product Page to Cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/328949/magento-2-passing-values-from-product-page-to-cart)