# Magento 2 Some item options or their combination are not currently available

Tags: magento2, addtocart

We have installed Magento ver. 2.1.6. using composer with sample data.

We have call event **checkout_cart_product_add_after** for adding addition information with item. The event observer code is given below.

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

    $additionalOptions = array();

    if ($additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')){
        $additionalOptions = (array) unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
    }

    $post = $this->_request->getParam('info');

    if(is_array($post)){
        foreach($post as $key => $value){
            if($key == '' || $value == ''){
                continue;
            }

            $additionalOptions[] = [
                'label' => $key,
                'value' => $value
            ];
        }
    }

    if(count($additionalOptions) > 0){
        $item->addOption(array(
            'code' => 'additional_options',
            'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
        ));
    }
```

When we add the configurable product with addition information in the cart then in shopping cart page display additional information with error  **Some item options or their combination are not currently available**

Comment: We have tried tired solution https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7488 but didn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cart Quote Item Option data stored in the quote_item_option table. This table contains option_id, item_id, product_id, code and value fields.

I have to pass **product_id, code and value** data to the **addOption** function but **missing to pass product_id**. Refer the following code

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();

    $additionalOptions = array();

    if ($additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')){
        $additionalOptions = (array) unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
    }

    $post = $this->_request->getParam('info');

    if(is_array($post)){
        foreach($post as $key => $value){
            if($key == '' || $value == ''){
                continue;
            }

            $additionalOptions[] = [
                'label' => $key,
                'value' => $value
            ];
        }
    }

    if(count($additionalOptions) > 0){
        $item->addOption(array(
            'product_id' => $item->getProductId(),//Missing data
            'code' => 'additional_options',
            'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
        ));
    }
```

Comment: I did the above thing and my **additional options** started coming in the **quote_item_option** table and gets displayed under product detail on **checkout/cart** page , but as soon as I refresh the **checkout/cart** page, the **additional_options** row gets deleted and it disappears from checkout/cart product. This doesn't happen with simple product. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: After testing couple of times, I came to know that this happens when user is logged in otherwise works perfectly fine

Comment: After more testing, I found out that the **additional_options** row for configurable product gets **deleted** from **quote_item_options**  table when I land on checkout/cart product, any idea where this happens and how to stop it?