# Magento 2 Programatically add product to cart with additional options

Tags: magento2, custom-options, addtocart, programmatically, additional-information

I want to add product to cart with some additional data. My code adds the product to cart,but the additional info is not saved properly.
I want to display the additional content in cart like custom option
http://i.prntscr.com/KzmHQqaNSYGhOt3buzlK1A.png

Here is my code

```
    namespace Namespace\Module\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Post extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_cart;
    protected $formKey;
    private $serializer;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, 
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface $serializer,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }    

    public function execute()
    {    
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $additionalOptions['print_style'] = [
            'label' => 'Print Style',
            'value' => 'Test',
        ];
        $params = array(
                'product' => 4,
                'qty' => 1,
                'options' => array('additional_options'=>$this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions)) 
            );
            $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById(4);
            $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
            $this->_cart->save();

        echo 'success';



    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I have used below code but getting error
Error > Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
> [Vendor_Name]\[Module_Name]\Controller\Index\Addplan::__construct()
> must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository,
> instance of Magento\Checkout\Model\ResourceModel\Cart given, called in
> /var/generation/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Controller/Index/Addplan/Interceptor.php
> on line 14 and defined in
> /app/code/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Controller/Index/Addplan.php:15
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/generation/[Vendor_Name]/[Module_Name]/Controller/Index/Addplan/Interceptor.

Comment: I trying to use that code in magento version 2.2.4 but after add to cart showing this error '1 exception(s): Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Unable to unserialize value.' please help me for that issue , Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133627)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/133627)

Comment: I got Unable to unserialize value. when used that extension. plz help me

Comment: @JancyAbraham have you get any solution.
I am looking for product option add custom value.
Please help on this question.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292966/magento-2-add-product-option-custom-value-in-product-rest-api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code works.
http://i.prntscr.com/cFUE8nuRQC2Veg4i3xo9OQ.png

```
        $productId = 4;
        $additionalOptions['print_style'] = [
            'label' => 'Print Style',
            'value' => 'Test'
        ];

        $params = array(
                'product' => $productId,
                'qty' => 1
            );
        $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
        $_product->addCustomOption('additional_options', $this->serializer->serialize($additionalOptions));
        $this->_cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
        $this->_cart->save();
```

Comment: I have used your code but getting error

Comment: how to update additional options

Comment: Please check "Web Spider"'s Answer.

Comment: @JancyAbraham : so will this effect on all sections like checkout summary,admin order section.Means we need to just add only in cart and will reflect all other sections?

Comment: Yes,it will display

Comment: Please help on this question.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292966/magento-2-add-product-option-custom-value-in-product-rest-api

Answer (score 2):

You may use 2 approaches here

1) You may use `setOptions()` method to set the custom options before adding product to cart
Your approach will be like

```
$customOptionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterfaceFactory');

$additionalOptions['print_style'] = [
        'label' => 'Print Style',
        'value' => 'Test',
    ];
$customOptions = [];

foreach ($additionalOptions['print_style'] as $option) {
    $customOption = $customOptionFactory->create(['data' => $option]);
    $customOption->setProductSku($_product->getSku());
    $customOptions[] = $customOption;
}
$_product->setOptions($customOptions);
$this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
$this->_cart->save();
```

for this approach you may take `dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/Catalog/_files/product_with_options.php` as reference

2) You may use `addCustomOption()` method on `$_product`
In this case your approach will be

```
 $additionalOptions['print_style'] = [
        'label' => 'Print Style',
        'value' => 'Test',
    ];
 $_product->addCustomOption('additional_options',serialize($additionalOptions));
```

P.S. Just in case you're curious to know how `addCustomOption()` is working , take a quick look on file

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product.php
```

Comment: Please help on this question.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292966/magento-2-add-product-option-custom-value-in-product-rest-api

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Observer checkout_cart_product_add_after to add custom data in additional_options

Here is full [Example](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132009/how-to-add-to-cart-a-product-with-custom-input-field-and-save-it-to-database/132482)

Comment: Sorry, I want to use the code in my custom controller. :-(

Answer (score 1):

This code works here :
[add products to cart with customizable options](https://takeoff.digital/case-studies/magento-2-add-products-to-cart-with-custom-options/)

```
$product = $productFactory->create();
$product->setStoreId(1)->load($product->getIdBySku($sku));
$params = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
$params->setQty($qty);
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) {
if ($value["sku"] == 'RED') { //add this if to search for your custom option by sku or the value name etc.
$options[$value['option_id']] = $value['option_type_ id'];
$params->setOptions($options); //set the customizable option to the product

}
}
}
try {
$quote1->addProduct($product, $params); //add to cart 
} catch (Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented using the event observer.
You can add following files in your module
**Namespace/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="namespace_module_checkout_cart_product_add_after" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Namespace/Module/Observer/CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver.php**

```
namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CheckoutCartProductAddAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(RequestInterface $request) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer) {
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $additionalOptions = array();

        if ($additionalOption = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
            $additionalOptions = (array) unserialize($additionalOption->getValue());
        }

       // $post = $this->_request->getParam('print_style'); // Your data added here
    $post = array('Print Style' = > 'Test');

        if (is_array($post)) {
            foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == '' || $value == '') {
                    continue;
                }

                $additionalOptions[] = array(
                    'label' => $key,
                    'value' => $value
                );
            }
        }

        if (count($additionalOptions) > 0) {
            $item->addOption(array(
                'product_id' => $item->getProductId(),
                'code' => 'additional_options',
                'value' => serialize($additionalOptions)
            ));
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If the method "$this->serializer->serialize" not works  then

use json_encode instead of serializer method.