# Magento2: allow cusotmer to customize a product

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, custom-attributes

I am developing a store on **Magento 2.1.x** which has a particular product that can be customized by the customer.
In detail It is a t-shirt on which can be printed a custom message inserted by the customer on the product page.
So, what I need is to show a text field on the product page where the customer can write his own message and, once the sale has been made, the store admin can read it on the backend and process the order.

Is it possible natively in Magento or should I use some extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Check below link hopefully it will help you.

[How to “add to cart” a product with custom input field and save it to Database](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132009/how-to-add-to-cart-a-product-with-custom-input-field-and-save-it-to-database/132482)

Answer (score 0):

It too old question but I really interested to answer this for all those who are looking for this. For customizing t-shirt you need to add an extension which called t-shirt designer or product designer. You can find easily at magento store or google.

It will allow your to customize their t-shirt as per they want.