# How to add custom option field added to every created product in Magento 2 added to products under specific category?

Tags: magento2, product

i am trying to add custom option programmitically to products created under specific category in Magento 2 , 
But it isn't easy at all doing this, i tried to search for a solution on the internet but all i found was to add custom options programmitically  with no clear instruction on how to make this code work,
also i need to get this custom option value to calculate the price in observer
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: This answer might be useful for you https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/132482/70510